# Calendar date picker

Tags: android

I want to open a calendar on click of a button as in this image:

[image]

I have used date picker in my code to open a calendar. Can anyone let me know how to get it to open as in the image I have posted? I have seen this in an app. This is the calendar that is opening now, for date selection:

[image]

Comment: i think this is useful link for u http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/custom-calendar-in-android.html

Comment: I think the first image is from the updated Calendar app, and the second one is the DatePicker widget.

Comment: Rollback on invalid edit that shouldn't have been approved...

Comment: so how could i get that

Comment: see this might be help full to u http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/

Answer (score 1):

Luckily android is open-source

so you can find what you are looking for in here

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/

also if you want it to work on pre ICS you can take a look in this library
(notice its missing some features)

https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker

Comment: i have seen this but how could i use this on click of button i need the same design that i have posted in my question

Comment: you going have to dig up in the code i gave you.. in the second link you can find his sample of how to use it , and how to set listener etc..https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker/blob/master/datetimepicker-sample/src/com/fourmob/datetimepicker/sample/MainActivity.java

Comment: i am also using datePickerDialog

Comment: i gave you the exact one like on your images, i guess you are using the standard android one which is different

Comment: i am new in android i am confused how i will use this if u can help me by some sample code i will be thanksfull to u